# Vectorize an operation in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to do the following on Numpy without using a loop :

- I have a matrix X of dimensions N*d and a vector y of dimension N.
  y contains integers ranging from 1 to K.
- I am trying to get a matrix M of size K*d, where M[i,:]=np.mean(X[y==i,:],0)

Can I achieve this without using a loop?

With a loop, it would go something like this.

```
import numpy as np

N=3
d=3 
K=2 

X=np.eye(N)
y=np.random.randint(1,K+1,N)
M=np.zeros((K,d))
for i in np.arange(0,K):
    line=X[y==i+1,:]
    if line.size==0:
        M[i,:]=np.zeros(d)
    else:
        M[i,:]=mp.mean(line,0)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does K == N? Are the values of y unique?

Comment: It would be cool if you showed some code.

Comment: No and no. For instance, if K=2, X=np.eye(3), Y=[1 2 1], i would like M to be [[1/2 0 1/2],[0 1 0]].

Comment: It would help if you wrote out the inputs as a short code snippet that we can run, e.g. `y = np.random.random_integers(low=1, high=K, size=N)` and `X = ?` and defining `K`, `N` and so on. It would be extra helpful to add some code that computes the output with a loop so we are crystal clear on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you aware the mean cannot be computed for `i=0` if you happen to have `y=[2, 2, 2]`?

Comment: Is `X` an identity matrix in your actual case too or does it have random numbers?

Comment: Similar question to @Divakar: Since you're comparing elements of `X` to indices, what can `X` contain in general and what is its `dtype`? Thanks for updating the question, much clearer now

Comment: So, did either of the solutions work for you?

Answer (score 3):

This solves the question, but creates an intermediate K×N boolean matrix, and doesn't use the built-in mean function. This may lead to worse performance or worse numerical stability in some cases. I'm letting the class labels range from `0` to `K-1` rather than `1` to `K`.

```
# Define constants
K,N,d = 10,1000,3

# Sample data
Y = randint(0,K-1,N) #K-1 to omit one class to test no-examples case
X = randn(N,d)

# Calculate means for each class, vectorized 

# Map samples to labels by taking a logical "outer product"
mark = Y[None,:]==arange(0,K)[:,None] 

# Count number of examples in each class    
count = sum(mark,1)

# Avoid divide by zero if no examples
count += count==0

# Sum within each class and normalize
M = (dot(mark,X).T/count).T

print(M, shape(M), shape(mark))
```

Answer (score 3):

The code's basically collecting specific rows off X and adding them for which we have a NumPy builtin in [`np.add.reduceat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html). So, with that in focus, the steps to solve it in a vectorized way could be as listed next -

```
# Get sort indices of y
sidx = y.argsort()

# Collect rows off X based on their IDs so that they come in consecutive order
Xr = X[np.arange(N)[sidx]]

# Get unique row IDs, start positions of each unique ID
# and their counts to be used for average calculations
unq,startidx,counts = np.unique((y-1)[sidx],return_index=True,return_counts=True)

# Add rows off Xr based on the slices signified by the start positions
vals = np.true_divide(np.add.reduceat(Xr,startidx,axis=0),counts[:,None])

# Setup output array and set row summed values into it at unique IDs row positions
out = np.zeros((K,d))
out[unq] = vals
```